# How can I make a cube with faces of different colors? Webgl

Tags: webgl, javascript

I have to draw cubes with faces of different colors (each per face), but I don't know how to accomplish this task: I draw cubes using CPU and GPU meshes (no vertexBuffer or three.js "style") and I don't know how to assign to each vertex different colors (I don't even know if this is possible).
I can upload my code to GitHub if my problem isn't clear enough, let me know.
All of this is coded in JavaScript and WebGL.

Comment: It's probably easier to do it with 3 copies of each vertex - with the appropriate colour on each copy.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please elaborate on your specific problem and show what you have so far. A code dump is not a proper way to do this. Extract the minimal and meaningful parts and post them in the question.

Comment: [This page](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html) describes drawing faces in different colors.

Answer (score -2):

There are many tutorials covering this - Google is your friend. Maybe [this](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/10/21/webgl-cube.html) covers your demands?

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript, but it looks to me like that is using a separate transformation per face. It might be ok for a trivial example, but *please* don't try to scale that to larger models.